# Get access token instagram

Tags: instagram, access-token

I try:

```
curl \-F 'client_id=CLIENT ID'     -F 'client_secret=CLIENT SECRET'     -F 'grant_type=authorization_code'     -F 'redirect_uri=URL'     -F 'code=CODE' \https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

And get:

> "Oops, an error occurred."

Answer (score 0):

You need to register an application at http://instagram.com/developer/ and replace your **CLIENT ID**, **CLIENT SECRET** with the ones generated by Instagram as well as the URL with one your app is on.

Comment: I did, I get as response "Oops, an error occurred." API is offline?